# Why do we use self-executing functions in the revealing module pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, revealing-module-pattern

I've been actively using the revealing module pattern for years but there's a few things I'd like to understand deeper. From what I understand potential benefits of self-executing functions are anoymimty & self-execution, both of which don't seem necessary/utilised in this particular pattern. The other thing I don't understand is, what in the below scenario makes its possible to wrap function Init inside the SocialMedia function(), i.e an embedded function, self-executing functions seem to be a very a unique construct in JS, isn't it strange that we can just assign a properties values to a self-executing code block?

```
var myObj = {
    prop1, "prop1value",
    SocialMedia: (function () {
        function Init() {

        }
        return  {
            Init: Init
        }
    })()
}
```

Comment: _"isn't it strange that we can just assign a properties values to a self-executing code block"_ - I don't think that's strange: you can assign a property to _any_ expression, so why not to the result of a function call? (Even a function call that doesn't return a value will work because effectively it returns undefined.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why do we use self-executing functions in the revealing module pattern?

JavaScript has first-class functions and lacks block-scoping, so functions are used to introduce new scopes.

> what in the below scenario makes its possible to wrap function Init inside the SocialMedia function(), i.e an embedded function
>   ... isn't it strange that we can just assign a properties values to a self-executing code block?

In JavaScript, a function is just an object that responds to the `()` and `new` operators.

Like other objects, you can use it when you define it, or store it in a variable or property for later use.

> self-executing functions seem to be a very a unique construct in JS

This isn't unique to JavaScript.  All languages that have [first class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) have this property, for example:

- Lisp,
- OCaml,
- Scala,
- Go,
- C# (via delegates),
- C (via fn ptrs),
- Python,
- Perl (via `&`),
- Ruby,
- Lua

In recent language development, first-class functions are the norm rather than the rule.  Un-statically-typed languages just make it easier because there's no overhead in the type system syntax and no [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_%28computer_science%29#Need_for_covariant_argument_types.3F) issues.

Even Java might be jumping on the bandwagon with [Lambdas slated for Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/).

In many of those other languages, immediately called functions aren't that useful though.  Most other languages are [block-scoped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Block_scope_within_a_function) so if you want to keep your variables separate, you just use a `{...}` block.  In JavaScript though, `var` is scoped to the smallest containing `function` or Program, so `function`s are the easiest way to introduce a new scope.

[Ruby](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) makes very little distinction between blocks and functions so could be considered similar to JS in this respect.

Answer (score 1):

Self-executing functions are used to introduce new scopes, see also Mike Samuels answer.

There are two reasons for that:

- avoid polluting the global scope
- use of closures, i.e. "exporting" a function from an extra scope

Of course you can stack scopes, but usually you won't create that big modules where you have to avoid polluting your local module scope :-)

Also, the self-executing function in your example is useless, as it's totally equivalent to

```
var myObj = {
    prop1: "prop1value",
    SocialMedia: {
        Init: function Init() {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i Normally put more methods inside, so Init, CreateButtons() etc, then I reference myObj.SocialMedia.Init(),